# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).….. While getting data from supabase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am having a problem while getting data from supabase .
Could any one help me

`

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { supabase } from "../../supabase"

async function Index(){

    const { data, error} = await supabase.from("Employees").select("*")

    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="container flex justify-center">
                <h1>Employees</h1>
            </div>

            
            {data.map((index) => {
                return (
                    <h1>{index.name}</h1>
                )
            })}
            

            <Link href="/employees/addemployee">
                <h1>Add employee</h1>
            </Link>
        </>
    )
}

export default Index;
```

`

I tried using map, other function, and looked it up yet nothing works

Comment: What is the type of `index.name`? if it's and Object, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you are fetching the data. Try fetching your data inside an useEffect hook:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { supabase } from "../../supabase";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Index() {
  // const { data, error } = await supabase.from("Employees").select("*")
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let cancelFetch = false; // to avoid race conditions on React18
    supabase
      .from("Employees")
      .select("*")
      .then((res) => {
        if (!cancelFetch) {
          setData(res.data);
          setError(res.error);
        }
      });
    return () => {
      cancelFetch = true;
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container flex justify-center">
        <h1>Employees</h1>
      </div>

      {data.map((index) => {
        return <h1>{index.name}</h1>;
      })}

      <Link href="/employees/addemployee">
        <h1>Add employee</h1>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}

export default Index;
```

More info on fetching and useEffect here: https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects

Answer (score 0):

Your source code is invalid. React components should always be a function (or class) that returns a react object. it does not accept a promise that returns a react object.

You will probably want to use react's `useEffect` to solve this problem:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { supabase } from "../../supabase"

async function Index(){
    const [data, setData] = useState()
    const [error, setError] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
      supabase.from("Employees").select("*")
        .then(data => setData(data))
        .catch(err => setError(err))
    }, [])
    
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="container flex justify-center">
                <h1>Employees</h1>
            </div>

            
            {data.map((index) => {
                return (
                    <h1>{index.name}</h1>
                )
            })}
            

            <Link href="/employees/addemployee">
                <h1>Add employee</h1>
            </Link>
        </>
    )
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component cannot be async, because it returns a Promise and React doesn't like that.

There is a cool function on Next.js that allows you to fetch data asynchronously, try that:

```
function Index({ data }) {    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="container flex justify-center">
                <h1>Employees</h1>
            </div>

            
            {data.map((index) => {
                return (
                    <h1>{index.name}</h1>
                )
            })}
            

            <Link href="/employees/addemployee">
                <h1>Add employee</h1>
            </Link>
        </>
    )
}

export default Index;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const { data, error} = await supabase.from("Employees").select("*")

    return {
         props: {
                data: data
         }
    }
}
```

More here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you are fetching data, I believe you are using next13 and you are in `app` directory. When you rendered `jsx`

```
     {data.map((index) => {
            return (
                <h1>{index.name}</h1>
            )
        })}
```

`index` refers to each element inside the data array. Most likely `index.name` is an object. that is why it is throwing that error.

```
     console.log("index name",index.name)
```

If you are using `async` functional component, you should be using `Suspense` api. Create a separeate component maybe `async Users`, fetch the data inside this component, and when you want to display the users inside the `Index`

```
import {Suspense} from "react"

function Index(){
  return (
    <>
    ....
      <Suspense fallback={ <h1>Users are loading...</h1>} >
          <Users/>
      </Suspense>
    ....
    </>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only use async component inside app folder and server component.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33602071)